# UIAlertview Button columns

Tags: iphone, button, uialertview

In iphone application can we set number of columns in UIAlertView as if I have six buttons in UIAlertView then how can I show it in 2 columns and 3 rows. If any one done it kindly share it how it will done ..

Any sample code will be extra help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `UIAlertView` is just a `UIView`. So you can manually add the buttons to the `UIAlertView` in a two column configuration. There is an example [here](http://icodeblog.com/2009/11/09/iphone-coding-tutorial-inserting-a-uitextfield-in-a-uialertview/) that demonstrates adding `UITextField`s, but I'm sure you can adapt it.

Note that having two many buttons in the `UIAlertView` might get Apple's back up ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I have done it like this

```
NSArray *subViewArray = Topicdialog.subviews;
    float y = 60.0f;

    for(int x=2;x<[subViewArray count];x += 2){

        UIView *button = [subViewArray objectAtIndex:x];

        CGRect frame = button.frame;
        frame.size.width = 120.0f;
        frame.size.height = 42.0f;
        frame.origin.x = 20.0f;
        frame.origin.y = y;
        button.frame = frame;

        UIView *button1 = [subViewArray objectAtIndex:x + 1];

        frame = button1.frame;
        frame.size.width = 120.0f;
        frame.size.height = 42.0f;
        frame.origin.x = 152.0f;
        frame.origin.y = y;
        button1.frame = frame;
        y = y + 48.0f;
    }
```

Comment: is it proper way to alight UIAlertView Buttons according to app store submission policy ... any review or idea will be appreciated